# Is it possible to pass data from CRM analytics column to Lightning flows?

Tags: callout, crm-analytics, flowscreen

Based on below link:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_dashboards_actions_configure.htm&type=5

I want to configure Custom action in CRM Analytics table where I want to pass data from 2 different columns to Lightning flows. I could not find any docs where if its possible to pass such information to Lightning flows.

Basically what I am trying to achieve here is to display some button in CRM analytics column and once I click on this button then I want to display the data from specific columns and Once I fetch the data then I will have to perform my operations further like to make a callout and fetch the URL from 3rd party application and launch the URL in separate tab.

Can someone please confirm if it's possible to pass such data to Flows from CRM anlytics column?